# Yii2. Download file from database BLOB field

Tags: download, yii2, blob

I saved a `png` image to `BLOB` field in database.

```
$model->content = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);
$model->save();
```

How can I download it now? I tried:

```
$model=$this->findModel($id);
header('Content-length: 362654');
header('Content-Type: png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$model->name_);
echo $model->content;
```

But after this the file was downloaded but with the size 1 kb instead 362654. And nothing inside file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.
With just a:

```
$model->content = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);
```

it is not possible to save content of file as `getInstanceByName` does not return it. In order to get content and save it in `db` `BLOB` field I used following code:

```
$file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);
$fp = fopen($file->tempName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, $file->size);
fclose($fp);
$model->content = $content;
$model->save();
```

So the problem was incorrect saving of the file.